# React update state synchronously

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I have a `Master` component that holds several `Child` components. Child state is kept in Master. The first state the child gets is, *FORM_LOADED*. Then I have the below code in my Master component.

```js
const Master = (props) => {
  const [formStates, setFormStates] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    setFormStates({...formStates, Master: "FORM_LOADED"})
  },[])

  render (
    <>
      <Child view="Model1" formStates={formStates} setFormStates={setFormStates} />
      <Child view="Model2" formStates={formStates} setFormStates={setFormStates} />
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(formStates, undefined, 4)}</pre>
    </>
  )
}

const Child = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    props.setFormStates({...props.formStates, [props.view]: "FORM_LOADED"})
  }, [])
  render (
    <p>{props.view}</p>
  )
}
```

My problem is that the state variable `formStates` always gets:

```json
{
  Master: "FORM_LOADED",
  Model2: "FORM_LOADED"
}
```

`Model1` doesn't appear in `formStates`. If I add more child components, only the last component is reflected in `formStates`. How can I get the Model1 to the `formStates`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand everything but in a setState() method you can get the old value.
You can do something like this:

````
  useEffect(() => {
    props.setFormStates((oldVal) =>({...oldVal, ...props.formStates, [props.view]: "FORM_LOADED" }));
  });
  return <p>{props.view}</p>;
};```
````

Comment: Thanks it worked. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html doesn't mention I can use previous state in useState hook

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you're overwriting your old object with the new one every time. Try:

```
const Child = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    props.setFormStates(prevFormStates => ({...prevFormStates, [props.view]: "FORM_LOADED"}))
  }, [])
  render (
    <p>{props.view}</p>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html doesn't mention I can use the previous state in useState hook

Answer (score 0):

Hello the approach you defined will never work because you are setting the state of the parent in the middle of a flow where a parent is in process to render its all child.

What I think is that you are trying to check if all of yours child has rendered.

**React waits to mount all child components before calling componentDidMount on the parent**

I think this can help you

Comment: I am using functional component (sorry I haven't mentioned it in my question above) and I get it solved following other answers (use of previous state)

Answer (score 0):

All code from every useEffect hooks is executed before same re-rendering. That is how React works. So every one of them uses old state of `formStates`.

You can use following code to use current state of `formState`:

```
const Master = (props) => {
  const [formStates, setFormStates] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    setFormStates((prev) => ({...prev, Master: "FORM_LOADED"}))
  },[])

  render (
    <>
      <Child view="Model1" formStates={formStates} setFormStates={setFormStates} />
      <Child view="Model2" formStates={formStates} setFormStates={setFormStates} />
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(formStates, undefined, 4)}</pre>
    </>
  )
}

const Child = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    props.setFormStates((prev) => ({...prev, [props.view]: "FORM_LOADED"}))
  }, [])
  render (
    <p>{props.view}</p>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html doesn't mention I can use the previous state in useState hook